# A question about Zsigmondy's Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Zsigmondy's theorem states that if $n>1$ is a positive integer and $ a>b>0 $ are coprime integers, then (with a few specific exceptions) there is a prime number $p$ (called a primitive prime divisor) that divides $a^{n}-b^{n}$ and does not divide $a^{k}-b^{k}$ for any positive integer $k<n$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem

Various reasonably elementary proofs of this result are known but my first question is whether there is an especially easy proof for $a=2,b=1$, a case known as Bang's Theorem.

The Wikipedia article given above states a similar result for $a^{n}+b^{n}$. Is there a good reference for this result and, again, is there  an especially easy proof for the case $a=2,b=1$?

Thank you.

Comment: The relation $ 2^n+1 = {2^{2n}-1\over 2^n-1} $ comes to mind but I have no space at the moment to go deeper into it.

Comment: Thanks @Gottfried Helms - that deals easily with my second question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to my second question** Based upon the comment from @Gottfried Helms

Suppose $n>1$ is a positive integer and $ a>b>0 $ are coprime integers. Also suppose that $a^{2n}-b^{2n}$ has a primitive prime factor $p$.

Then $p$ is not a factor of  $a^n-b^n$ and is therefore a factor of $a^n+b^n$. For $k<n$, $p$ is not a factor of  $a^{2k}-b^{2k}$ and is therefore not a factor of $a^k+b^k$. $p$ is therefore a primitive prime factor of $a^n+b^n$.

This means that the theorem for $a^n+b^n$ follows easily from that for $a^n-b^n$.